# how do I fix "The name 'script' does not exist in the current context"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this code below, but I get an error and can't fix it.
The error:

> The name `script` does not exist in the current context.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowCube: MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject cube;
    public Vector3 cubePov;
    public Vector3 cubePovStart;
    public Vector3 camPov;

    void Start()
    {
        cube = GameObject.Find("Cube");
        CollisionDetection script = cube.GetComponent<CollisionDetection>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        cubePov = (GameObject.Find("Cube")).transform.position;
        camPov = transform.position;
        if (script.CollisionDown == true)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: By not defining it as a local variable but a field .... also if you already have the `cube` why would you use `Find` again every frame when getting its position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what that means is, the variable 'script' hasn't been declared in the `Update()` method. You're declaring 'script' in the `Start()` method. If you need it to be available to both declare it up next to the "public Vector3" and then both locations can access it. But do note, if you declare it, it has to be set to something before it can be used still.  In the below, I moved its scope so both can access it.

Again to reiterate, `Start()` must be called before `Update()` otherwise a null exception will occur because you initialize it (set it to something) in `Start()`.

I'm not well versed in Unity but if there is any chance that `GameObject.Find` might return a null object if what you're asking for is not found then you would want to put a check in to handle that or at least be aware of it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowCube : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cube;
    public Vector3 cubePov;
    public Vector3 cubePovStart;
    public Vector3 camPov;
    public CollisionDetection script;

    void Start()
    {
        cube = GameObject.Find("Cube");
        script = cube.GetComponent<CollisionDetection>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        cubePov = (GameObject.Find("Cube")).transform.position;
        camPov = transform.position;

        if (script.CollisionDown == true)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`script` exists just in `Start()` method; so that' why it is not visible in the `Update()` method. Declare it globally, and then reuse it (in case if those are static class methods).

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared inside methods can not be used in other methods. You are declaring `script` in `Start()`, but trying to use it in `Update()`. Just make it a global variable (a.k.a declare it on the top of your code) and you should be good to go!